# Xcode + Time Machine (or Finder copy) = NSInternalInconsistencyException

Tags: objective-c, xcode, ios-simulator, finder

After using Finder to make a copy of my project, the iPhone Simulator crashes giving me an NSInternalInconsistencyException error.  I subsequently used Time Machine to restore the project before I made the copy, but am still getting the NSInternalInconsistencyException error.

This is a small homework assignment and re-creating it wouldn't be the end of the world.  My big concern is that I don't understand something fundamental about how Xcode is working.  Any illumination would be greatly appreciated.

**Update**

Apple identified the bug.  The iPhone Simulator keeps the last-run version of the app onboard, and doesn't replace it with the copied/Time-Machine-Restored version that is in Run-and-Build.  Deleting the app from the iPhone Simulator and performing a new Run-and-Build resolves the issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sounds like a bug. Your source code files should be fine, so hopefully it's not a big deal to just create a new project and add those files so that you can get back to work. You might also want to [report the issue](http://bugreport.apple.com/) to Apple, especially if you can make it happen again.

Comment: Thanks, Caleb, I'm actually glad to hear that because my primary concern was that I had a fundamental misunderstanding of how Xcode handles project files.

I was able to recreate the project doing exactly what you suggested, creating a new project and adding all of the files back by using "Add Files To <MyProjectName>".

Comment: Update: Filed bug report with Apple.  I'd vote up Caleb's response but I'm new and I need a rep of 15 to vote :(